# Alternate way to write to csv and xls file using html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins

I am using **Activex** in my code to write into xls(excel) file. But the problem is activex is only supported by Internet Explorer. Is the any **script** or **jquery** script that can be used to export the value from xml or javascript variable to excel as **csv** or **xsl**. Code or demo highly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: you can write XSLT to transform xml to csv.have look at dis: [xml to csv](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/952365/how-do-i-write-an-xslt-to-transform-xml-to-csv)

Comment: dup? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7508063/creating-an-xls-or-csv-file-from-a-javascript-variable

Comment: @MilindAnantwar thanks i will try to learn more about xslt

Comment: @sje397 but there only activex code provided :(

Comment: This might get you started? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6965107/converting-between-strings-and-arraybuffers